# loading json file using python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to load json file availalble here : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/e5ef9cb96acb98e1f813d5166d472c70/raw/eabf219c51ace122ad82b7037bbf93d347fb4a9b/data.json

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/home/karimk/python/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/home/karimk/python/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/karimk/python/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 - line 6 column 740 (char 2826 - 16384)
```

What wrong am I doing here?

Comment: Validation of that JSON failed. Try [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Paste the JSON and check if it is vaid.

Answer (score 0):

What wrong : json is not valid
Solution : update data to be a valid json, by example remove end of line inside string item.